# creating a .net core 3.0 class library problems

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to create a .Net Core 3.0 class library to link to my newly created WPF .Net Core 3.0 App project, but I cannot find the option in the "Create a new project" dialog.

I have VS2019 v16.3.1

Am I going mad or is there another project type I should be using?

Comment: file > new > project , isn't that exist?

Comment: There is a `Class Library (.NET Core)` project template as well if you only target .NET Core.

Comment: @Lance: Can't you find the templates or what is you issue here?

Comment: You right click the solution. Choose Add> New Project. You get a dialogue says "Add a new project". In the "search for templates" box type class library (.Net Core)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the new .net core 3?
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-3.0.100-windows-x64-installer

Comment: I installed the download above, upgraded to VS16.3.2 and the "Class Library (.Net Core) appeared in the add new project dialog.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Tools -> Get Tools and Features (You might need to update the installer)
2. Make sure that ".NET Core cross-platform development" is checked and installed

If for some reason you still cant find .NET Core 3.0 projects, you might need to use Visual Studio 2019 **Preview**.

Answer (score 0):

1. right click on your solution and select add/new project.
2. class library (.NET Core) is available for me.